# Sound card not found anymore

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I started my ubuntu today and Audio card was not working. Card is not even listed with `lshw`.  No device with description like `physical id: 1b` (I remember the old device settings).

Any ideas?

Comment: did you update/install/change anything recently?

Comment: No update recently

Comment: what is the output when you `lsmod|grep '^snd' | column -t` or `ls -l /sys/module/snd/holders` ?

Comment: Might it simply have slipped out of its socket?

Comment: @Stefan `ls -l /sys/module/snd/holders` result: `ls: cannot access /sys/module/snd/holders: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Stefan `lsmod|grep '^snd' | column -t` result: nothing

Comment: @fschmitt it's onboard sound card

Comment: @amra, wow... well... take a look at the link in my answer... hope it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be caused by any number of things, you should take a look at the [Comprehensive Sound Problem Solutions Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449) on the Ubuntu Forums

---

Exerpt from the [Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449):

> (2) Type this into the shell: Code:
>
> ```
> lspci -v
> ```
>
> **Success** - At this point, you should see your sound card listed.
>   This is a positive sign because it
>   means that Ubuntu is detecting the
>   presence of your soundcard, but the
>   drivers are not installed/running.
>   Leave your shell running since you
>   will need it.
>
> **Failure** - If it is not listed, then there are a few things that you
>   can do.
>
> - If your soundcard is an onboard sound card, then it might be
>     disabled in the system's BIOS. You
>     will have to reboot and hit the key
>     that lets you enter into the BIOS
>     (usually Delete, F2, or F.
> - If your soundcard is not onboard, make sure that it is properly
>     seated in the PCI slot. If your card
>     is working under Windows then this is
>     not a problem.

Comment: `lspci` doesn't list audio card. I checked BIOS and it's enables. I think this is final stage `:o(`

Comment: did you try re-installing all the drivers?

Comment: in my case, the module wasn't inserted into the kernel at startup (probably kernel was updated and something broke), so I did `modprobe snd_hda_intel` and sound appeared again